# Reducing weight in custom loss function with step increase

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I would like to change a weight imposed on loss as step increases. To achieve that, I use a [subclass of tf.keras.losses.Loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#custom_losses). However, arguments in its functions like __init__() or call() can't seem to get step during calculations.

How can I get a step number in a subclass of tf.keras.losses.Loss?

Here is my code.

```
class CategoricalCrossentropy(keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, weight, name="example"):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.weight = weight

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):

        weight = self.weight*np.exp(-1.0*step) #I'd like to use step number here to reduce weight.
        loss = -tf.reduce_sum(weight*y_true*tf.math.log(y_pred))/y_shape[1]/y_shape[2] #impose weight on CategoricalCrossentropy
        
        return loss
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit (Its because you haven´t told the function what the value of step is, this will be a local variable which the function won´t be able to collect as it has its has its own local variables.)

I´m presuming you are setting the step through an iteration. Simply add it as an input into the call function.

```
class CategoricalCrossentropy(keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, weight, name="example"):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.weight = weight

    def call(self, step, y_true, y_pred):

        weight = self.weight*np.exp(-1.0*step) #I'd like to use step number here to reduce weight.
        loss = -tf.reduce_sum(weight*y_true*tf.math.log(y_pred))/y_shape[1]/y_shape[2] #impose weight on CategoricalCrossentropy
        
        return loss

keras_weight = 1
keras_example = CategoricalCrossentropy(keras_weight)

for step in range(1, max_step+1):     # assuming step cannot = 0
    loss = keras_example.call(1, y_true, y_perd)
```

If you want the step to be something the object remembers you can simply add an atribute.

```
class CategoricalCrossentropy1(keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, weight, name="example"):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.weight = weight
        self.step = 1           #again, assuming step cannot = 0

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        weight = self.weight*np.exp(-1.0*self.step) #I'd like to use step number here to reduce weight.
        loss = -tf.reduce_sum(weight*y_true*tf.math.log(y_pred))/y_shape[1]/y_shape[2] #impose weight on CategoricalCrossentropy
        
        self.step += 1  # add to step

        return loss
```

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Somehow, I've been overthinking about custom loss function.

Comment: Glad it helped! Happens to us all when we get bogged down in code